# MongoDB connect failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My problem here is that even after setting up mongod.exe "mongod.exe --install --logpath c:\mongodb\logs --logappend  --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db --directoryperdb", when i start up mongo.exe on another shell, i get a connection error

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
>   connecting to: test                                                             2016-10-01T17:20:11.543+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
>   2016-10-01T17:20:11.543+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :                                connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

what is it that i'm not doing right? Running it on Windows 10. Mongod.exe after set up waits for a connection.

Answer (score 0):

> it is may be because of the OS privileges so for example if you are in
>   windows try to open  the cmd(command line) in administrator mode and
>   try to start the MongoDB server again,i hope this fix your problem

Comment: try that :
after opening the cmd in administrator mode write this without double quotation and pres enter  "net start MongoDB" 
you 'll get a message "The MongoDb service is starting"

Comment: did that, have it installed as a service, but when i start mongo it still doesn't connect and gives me the error, even on cmd as admin, it stiil doesn't connect, tried using Robomongo and other related tools but there still isn't a connection

Answer (score -1):

This is because the db server must be running and waiting for connections. I think you should start your db server first with `./mongod` in the root directory and leave it running. Hopefully this will help!

Comment: hey, so what I did is I installed all windows updates cause I hadn't since upgrading to windows 10 then reinstalled it and it worked perfectly, if i remember clearly i kept running mongod in one terminal then running it again in another rather than just running it once and mongo in another, anyway thanks for the feedback, very much appreciated